# Unity Physics Trouble with Platform Objects

Tags: unity, physics, game-design

Hi Game Development Community!
I'm new to designing in unity, and I'm having some issues with my player game object traveling through platform game objects. Several of my game objects (pink in pictured) are successfully acting as a surface for the ball (purple). But others (cylinders in white) are not. The ball goes straight through them. Yet I'm not seeing a difference in the cylinder and cube's physics settings I've set. Any advice or solutions to this problem are much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hey select the game object which is not colliding properly and check whether "isTrigger" is on , if it is then turn it off. Also make sure your collider size is covering the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Unity cylinder colliders. The unity cylinder collider isn't a *cylinder* but a *capsule*.

Uncheck the Mesh Renderer component of the cylinder and you will see the collider as green outline.

You need to add a mesh collider by clicking *Add Component* below.

I hope this sufficiently answers your question.